# React Native pan along a circle

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated

I am doing a player with a circular progress bar.
This player has 2 functionalities:

1. The handle moves automatically every second (as the song plays)
2. The circular progress bar has a handle that a user can move (for song scrubbing)

For the first task, I used a timer that updates an `Animated.Value` from 0 to 1 (based on song duration) and interpolates the values to degrees. It works fine.

But how do I do the second task?
I tried using a `PanResponder` with `Animated.Event` inside `onPanResponserMove`, but I just could not make it work.

```
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY()
   this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
   onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
   onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => return Animated.event([
null, {
     dx: this.pan.x,
     dy: this.pan.y,
   }])(e, gestureState),
   onPanResponderRelease: () => {
   },
  });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <Animated.Image
       {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
       style={[{translateY: this.pan.y}, {translateX: this.pan.x}, {rotate: this.pan.x.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
            })]}>
       {this.props.children}
     </Animated.Image>
   );
 }
}
```

Please advise.
Thank you!

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Anyone can help please?